# Trouble creating a KotlinJS component that returns React context - how can I fix the 'return not allowed here' error?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, kotlin-js

I am working in code immigration that is written in reactjs to kotlinjs with react.
I have problem with react context issues.
In kotlinjs I have to create a component that should return Context.
The  component definitions should look like in the code below

`

```
import kotlinx.browser.localStorage

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import react.*


val MyContext = createContext("");
@Serializable
data class UserInfo(val userId: Int, val username: String)


//const DataContextProvider = (props) => {

val DataContextProvider = FC<Props> {
    var username by useState("test5555");
    MyContext.Provider({ username })

    //check current user and set user id each time user refresh page
    useEffect( {
        var res = localStorage.getItem("userInfo")

        var userInfo = Json.decodeFromString<UserInfo>(res?:"");
        if (userInfo?.userId != null) {
            username = userInfo.username;
        }
    });
    return (MyContext)

}`
```

It gives me that "'return' is not allowed here"

Can you help with that?

I try to not use a function but It does not help.